# setcookie("user", "", time()-3600) not working

Tags: php, cookies

I tried to use `setcookie("user", "", time()-3600)` to delete a cookie from php, but it's not working for me, when I check in the tool of the broswer, the cookie seems to still exist. Does anyone know why?

note: this is the domain cookies.. mean I set this cookies with this way `setcookie('user','true',time() + 2592000,"/",".user.com",0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setcookie ('user', "", time() - 3600, "/", ".user.com", 1);
Just a warning- IE and opera sometimes maintain cookie values until after restart- that may be part of the issue.

Comment: I'm using Opera and have had not problems with that in my development!  Just make sure you are expiring it on the correct domain.   I can't vouch for IE... wouldn't touch it.

Answer (score 1):

```
setcookie("user", 0, time()-3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/setcookie), your code should work properly, though, you could try this:

```
setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".user.com", 0);
```